# Project Structure form in Android Studio doesn't have librareis

Tags: android-studio, junit

I want in Android Studio to add JUnit library but in Project Structure form it doesn't exist. I work in android studio version 2.1.2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

click on **dependency** TAB  and click on **+** button

then select **add library dependency**

or directly add

`testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

this line into

```
dependencies {

}
```

into your module level **build,gradle**

Comment: In Choose Library Dependency, JUnit doesn't exist.